# How do I move an audio clip to a different track within the same project?

Tags: audacity

I have a project that represents an album of songs, and what I'd like to do is move one song into another song's track so the first song plays after the second song. Unfortunately, the Webpages and videos I looked at deal solely with moving clips to different positions within the same clips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used Audacity, but if your tracks are all open in the same window, you should just be able to select the desired audio from one track, copy it, then place your cursor on the destination track at the desired location and paste. Then you can delete your first track if you no longer need it.